# Float right without clearing previous float(s)

Tags: html, css, css-float

I know the obvious solution is to wrap `banner` and `main` in a float container, but is there any other way to 'bump' `sidebar` to the top, given the constraints of the HTML below?

http://html-bin.appspot.com/aghodG1sLWJpbnIMCxIEUGFnZRjJ0wYM

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Floats</title>
    <style>

        #banner {
            width: 70%;
            float: left;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }

        #main {
            width: 70%;
            float: left;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid orange;
        }

        #sidebar {
            width: 25%;
            float: right;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="banner">
        Banner
    </div>

    <div id="main">
        Main
    </div>

    <div id="sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you want the main and side bar to fill the height of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#sidebar {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
    .display: inline;
    .zoom:1;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 22%;
}
```

Comment: Awesome - almost (IE7 says nay).

Comment: How are you testing for IE7? I use a Spoon.net compile & it's having none of it!

Comment: Hmmm... I was always worried how "true" my copy was to a native install. On reflection, I'm going to get around the constraints (it's a quirky template) and try and work in a float wrapper for peace of mind - appreciate all your help though!